# how to edit existing debian package in installation cd?

Tags: installation, debian, package, edit, cd

ive been trying to edit a Debian installation CD, 
followed tutorial on debian website
https://wiki.debian.org/DebianInstaller/Modify/CD,
successfully extract cd, use genisoimage to recreate iso, try to install debian, no problem.

and then the problem, when i tried to edit one of the package, say i want to change a picture in a package .deb, i used this command:

extract .deb:

```
mkdir directoryname
cd directoryname
dpkg-deb -x pathtopackage/package_name.deb .
dpkg-deb -e pathtopackage/package_name.deb
```

building .deb :

```
dpkg-deb -b . pathtopackage/new_package_name.deb
```

and replaced the very same package on /pool/main debian cd directory
however after built the iso, it failed to install my edited package,

i've tried to fix md5 sum inside cd, rebuild dist/Release, still no luck. 
any advice?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally did it.

first mistake

building .deb :

```
dpkg-deb -b . pathtopackage/new_package_name.deb
```

correct command:

```
dpkg-deb -b -Zgzip . pathtopackage/new_package_name.deb
```

to recreate exact package as original one

and then following the rest tutorial on https://wiki.debian.org/DebianInstaller/Modify/CD,

except for debootstrap error, it can be done by following tutorial from this page 
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/debootstrap/+bug/1001131

edit my debootstrap.deb, repackage, and voila, done all the works.

apparently my error was because debootstrap error from official debian page doesnt work for me.

hope this information useful for anyone